# trying to change cell image once clicked, doesnt change upon click

Tags: javascript, html

I m trying to change the img on the cell once i click on it, however that does not happen, an explanation and a solution would be nice.

I am manually setting gBoard[0][0].isFlagged to true, and then clicking the cell, the img does not change.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="css/game.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <h1>Welcome to minesweeper</h1>
    <div class="board-container"></div><button class="restart-Btn" onclick="restartGame(this)">restartGame</button> 
    <script src="js/utils.js">
    </script> 
    <script src="js/game.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script**

```
const TILE = '<img src="/img/tile.png" >'
const TWO = '<img src="/img/2.png" >'

function printMat(mat, selector) {
    var strHTML = '<table border="1"><tbody>';
    for (var i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        strHTML += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0; j < mat[0].length; j++) {
            var className = `cell-${i}-${j}`
            strHTML +=
                `<td class="${className}" 
              onclick="cellClicked(this, ${i}, ${j})">
                <img src="${mat[i][j].image}" >
            </td>`
        }
        strHTML += '</tr>'
    }
    strHTML += '</tbody></table>';
    var elContainer = document.querySelector(selector);
    elContainer.innerHTML = strHTML;
}

function createBoard(size) {
    var board = []
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        board[i] = []
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            board[i][j] = creatCell()
        }
    }
    return board
}

function creatCell() {
    return {
        isBomb: false,
        isFlagged: false,
        isClicked: false,
        isOpen: false,
        image: "/img/tile.png"
    }
}
function cellClicked(elCell, i, j) {

    if (gBoard[i][j].image === TILE && gBoard[i][j].isFlagged === true) {

        elCell.innerHTML = TWO
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a little of the relevant HTML?

Comment: the html only got a div containter to push the matrix into

Comment: I guess something that shows where these functions are getting called and what the values of things like `elCell` are would help.

Comment: Or a JSFiddle or something with an example we can work with.

Comment: well in the printmat functions, i add an onclick to every cell, that onclick returns the elment that i clicked on and the location                                                                         <td class="${className}" 
              onclick="cellClicked(this, ${i}, ${j})">
                <img src="${mat[i][j].image}" >
            </td>`

Comment: Are you sure that cellClicked() is running, and that the first conditional is evaluating to true? You've set the second portion to true, but the first could be false.

Comment: its always a tile at first, it shows here:                                                                                                `<td class="${className}" 
              onclick="cellClicked(this, ${i}, ${j})">
                <img src="${mat[i][j].image}" >
            </td>`                                                                                                                       and the cellclicked should run at the instance i click

Comment: What is `mat` supposed to be? I'm trying to replicate this and help but not providing the init code isn't making it easy haha.

Comment: the mat is the board created by CreatBoard function, thx for trying tho dude:D

Comment: Don't use string composition. You already have your board set up, so just get the `<img>` element from inside the cell that you clicked, and change its `.src` attribute to point to the new image's URL. Done. No need to mess with expensive and error prone string compositing and then forcing a partial document rebuild.

Comment: can u write an example code? would clarify your answer much more

Comment: How is the function being called from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the `cellClicked()` function, the first comparison is not right. `TILE` holds a string with the entire `<img>`element but `gBoard[i][j].image` is just the value of the `src` attribute, so this comparison:

```
gBoard[i][j].image === TILE
```

Is really comparing:

```
'<img src="/img/tile.png" >' === '/img/tile.png'
```

Which won't ever be true.

I got it to work by setting up a new variable, `tileSrc`:

```
const TILE = '<img src="/img/tile.png" >'
const tileSrc = '/img/tile.png';
```

Then in the conditional in `cellClicked()`, test against that:

```
if (gBoard[i][j].image === tileSrc && gBoard[i][j].isFlagged === true)
```

You can see it working here: [Tiles App](https://tiles-ds.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the function is being called in the console.

Without the HTML I can't know for sure this is the issue but I had an issue of images not updating, but then I found out I had to 'force refresh' the image by adding a time stamp.

Maybe try:

```
function cellClicked(elCell, i, j) {
    if (gBoard[i][j].image === TILE && gBoard[i][j].isFlagged === true) {
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        elCell.innerHTML = TWO + '?' + timestamp
    }
}
```

Comment: the HTML:

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/game.css">
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <h1> Welcome to minesweeper</h1>


        <div class="board-container">

            
           </div>


    <button class="restart-Btn" onclick="restartGame(this)">restartGame</button>

    <script src="js/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="js/game.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>